# When I try to knit my R file into PDF, only smart portion of the plot is shown in the PDF file

Tags: r

So, when I plot the functions using curve function in R file and fix the x limits as :`curve(x, from = -2, to = 2, ...)` then the graph display shows me the full graph as it should be, but when I knit the document, the outputted on the PDF file only the small portion of the plot is shown. Here is the r markdown chunk:

```r
plot.new()
curve(dnorm(x), from = -5, to = 5, col = "blue", add = TRUE, lwd = 2, lty = 2)
curve(dt(x, 25), from = -5, to = 5, col = "red", add = TRUE, xlab = "quantile", 
    ylab = "density", lwd = 2)
curve(dt(x, 8), from = -5, to = 5, col = "green", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
curve(dt(x, 2), from = -5, to = 5, col = "dark red", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
curve(dt(x, 1), from = -5, to = 5, col = "grey40", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
legend("topleft", legend = c("N(0,1)", paste0("DF = ", c(1, 2, 8, 25))), 
    col = c("blue", "grey40", "sky blue", "green", "red"), lty = c(2, 1, 
        1, 1, 1), lwd = 2)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: this is probably because `plot.new()` has nothing to go with when you knit. Try using `plot(NULL, ...)` and adding xlim and ylim parameters to it

Comment: Why use `plot.new` at all?  Just leave out `add = TRUE` from the first `curve()` call.